# Netlogo: Changing a certain size of patches

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create two patches with different colors + opposite locations and a certain size (needs to form a square). I'm having a hard time getting "the certain size" done. How do I do this?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Can you provide a picture showing what you want? Also, code of what you've tried is always good to include.

Comment: Hi @Bryan Head, i'm sorry.
I want to create a Slider that assigns a variable size to each of the armies (patches) and that size should form a square.

Example: 1 Patches, 2 Patches, 4 Patches, 8 Patches, etc.

The two different "armies" must have opposing positions

Comment: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/Moore&VonNeumannExample